# HTML irregular layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to create page with an interesting layout, see bellow

[Example of the layout intented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrYbZ.png)

Problem I'm having is that I'm not sure of the best way to approach this.

I'm using bootstrap, and what I've done so far is:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="shapes" style="background: #FFF">
    <h1>Here's where the shapes will happen.</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" id="content" style="background: #999">
    <h1>page content</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

My idea is to create 2 columns, where the smaller one on the left (col-md-4), is the one that is shaped, and the other one is the page content.

I'm having trouble in creating the shapes, any ideas on how can I approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are heading in right direction as far as columns are concerned. For the shape you can create them by drawing right triangles and later adding them to the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by using the [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to put two divs side by side then using the `clip-path: polygon(` tool to clip the div how you wish. example

```css
#shapes {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 94% 16%, 98% 37%, 93% 59%, 100% 91%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 94% 16%, 98% 37%, 93% 59%, 100% 91%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  background: #323232;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="shapes">
      <h1>Here's where the shapes will happen.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="content">
      <h1>page content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)  is a great tool for making polygon clips.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.